# Mongo concurrency - collection.find() returns duplicate documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb

We use mongdb version 3.6.2 and NodeJS clients version 3.1.10. When executing collection.find() and collection.updateOne() from different processes concurrently we can relatively easily reproduce a scenario where we get duplicate documents returned by collection.find().

Our collection "schema" essentially looks like this:

```
{
  _id : "uuid"
  tenantId: "string",
  name: "string",
  created: "date",
  lastUpdated: "date"
}
```

Our indices look like this:

```
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_",
    "ns" : "users.users"
},
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "tenantId" : 1,
        "name" : 1
    },
    "name" : "tenantId_1_name_1",
    "ns" : "users.users"
}
>
```

Then we concurrently run several read and update operations on a SINGLE record in the database.

To setup the test, we execute `creator.js`:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/users'
const collectionName = 'users'
const userId = 'FGw8RXxaohfcVy1Ue4_qa9cFNEj1il-j'
const tenantId = 'ksuUOItGisnBpyMdCD8a0SGoOTNqRbJc'

async function start () {
  let client = await MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  let db = client.db()
  let usersCollection = db.collection(collectionName)

  await createIndex(usersCollection, { tenantId: 1, name: 1 })

  const now = new Date()

  await usersCollection.insertOne({
    _id: userId,
    tenantId,
    name: 'February',
    created: now,
    lastUpdated: now
  })

  console.log(`created user: ${userId} in tenant: ${tenantId}`)
}

async function createIndex (collection, keys, options) {
  return collection.createIndex(keys, options)
}

start().then(() => {
  console.log('done!!!')
  process.exit(0)
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

The updates are executed from the `updater.js`:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/users'
const collectionName = 'users'
const userId = 'FGw8RXxaohfcVy1Ue4_qa9cFNEj1il-j'

async function start () {
  let client = await MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  let db = client.db()
  let usersCollection = db.collection(collectionName)

  // keep updating:
  let toggle = false
  while (true) {
    toggle = !toggle
    let userData = await usersCollection.findOne({ _id: userId })
    if (!userData) {
      throw new Error(`no users with id: ${userId}`)
    }
    await usersCollection.updateOne({
      _id: userId
    }, {
      '$set': {
        ...userData,
        lastUpdated: new Date(),
        name: toggle ? 'January' : 'February'
      }
    })
    await sleep(1)
  }
}

function sleep (milliseconds) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
}

start().then(() => {
  console.log('done!!!')
  process.exit(0)
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

The reads are executed from the `reader.js`:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/users'
const collectionName = 'users'
const tenantId = 'ksuUOItGisnBpyMdCD8a0SGoOTNqRbJc'

async function start () {
  let client = await MongoClient.connect(uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
  })
  let db = client.db()
  let usersCollection = db.collection(collectionName)

  // keep reading:
  while (true) {
    let cursor = await usersCollection.find({
      tenantId: tenantId
    }, {
      sort: { tenantId: 1, name: 1 },
      hint: { tenantId: 1, name: 1 },
      limit: 10
    })
    let users = await cursor.toArray()
    if (users.length !== 1) {
      throw new Error(`weird number of users obtained: ${JSON.stringify(users, null, 2)}`)
    }
    await sleep(1)
  }
}

function sleep (milliseconds) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
}

start().then(() => {
  console.log('done!!!')
  process.exit(0)
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

The errors reproducible when running 12 instances of `updater.js` and 3 instances of `reader.js` (sometimes really quickly and sometimes after a few minutes) look like this (and originate in `reader.js`):

```
Error: weird number of users obtained: [
  {
    "_id": "FGw8RXxaohfcVy1Ue4_qa9cFNEj1il-j",
    "tenantId": "ksuUOItGisnBpyMdCD8a0SGoOTNqRbJc",
    "name": "February",
    "created": "2019-03-07T15:46:28.238Z",
    "lastUpdated": "2019-03-07T16:01:37.504Z"
  },
  {
    "_id": "FGw8RXxaohfcVy1Ue4_qa9cFNEj1il-j",
    "tenantId": "ksuUOItGisnBpyMdCD8a0SGoOTNqRbJc",
    "name": "January",
    "created": "2019-03-07T15:46:28.238Z",
    "lastUpdated": "2019-03-07T16:01:37.507Z"
  }
]
```

Note: "_id" and "created" fields are the same in both records.

We need to be able to sort by "name" efficiently, which is why we indexed the data by it. We also need to be able to change the "name" periodically. Is there a way to avoid or mitigate this kind of duplication while preserving the functionality we need (paging/sorting)? Are there any common ways to deal with this at the database level or in application code?

Comment: find method return all collection data  you need to filter after result

Comment: three points inside $set object is for spreading  the rest of the document? that may be causing the problem.

Comment: @vitomadio: Goodness, sorry for the confusion! I put the three dots inside `set` as pseudo code to show we're also setting other fields. I've edited the question.

Comment: @Ajay yadav: yes, we are after all records in the collection. There just happens to be 1 there in our tests. And sometimes, the database returns 2.

Comment: So `_id` is a Primary Key and actually impossible to have the same value, which means the problem is in your "tests" not producing the correct output. Please update your post with the [**Smallest Possible** code listing in order to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then someone can point out what is wrong with that code.

Comment: @Neil Lunn: I updated the question whith minimal code snippets required to reproduce the error. Thanks again for helping us dig into this.

Comment: The problem with your test is you presume there is data in the collection to begin with. A unit test ( or MCVE ) should not presume that and be self contained, creating data and testing the operation. You need to "reproduce" on a "clean collection". Also `tennantId !== userId`, which really should be a glaring point of the main thing that is wrong here.

Comment: @Neil Lunn: Let me explain the gist of the issue again. The records in the collection have `_id` property (i.e. `userId` in code). The users are partitioned by `tenantId` (think of it as company ID). Users for `tenant` A are different than users for `tenant` B. The `creator.js` populates just 1 user in the collection (for 1 tenant). The 12 `updater.js` instances keep loading and modifying the `name` and `lastUpdated` properties on that user concurrently. The 3 `reader.js` instances keep reading up to 10 users from that tenant (also concurrently) and sometimes get the same user twice.

Comment: Really, there's nothing to explain. Your code does not "reproduce the problem" as I have explained. It's not possible to duplicate `_id` and if you follow my instructions for "reproducible" then you will discover that yourself. This code does not verify that.

Comment: @Neil Lunn: The `creator.js` is meant to be run as test setup. If you run the `creator.js` first and then several instances of `updater.js` and `creator.js` each concurrently, you should be able to reproduce this issue. They should all be modifying/reading the same record over and over again, but the readers sometimes see that record duplicated (including duplicate `_id`).